# Batch File Change System Clock Time

Tags: batch-file, time, timer, windows-xp, scheduled-tasks

We use a PC that isnt connected to the internet but requires the time to be updated due to logging. The PC is running windows XP and I wanted to mabe create a batch file that would change the clocks time for daylight saving when it comes posibly using the PC's Task Scheduler? What code would go in the batch file to get the time to move forward in spring and back in fall?

Thanks!

Comment: IMHO Windows `XP` is configurable to [Automatically adjust clock for Daylight saving changes](http://askville.amazon.com/windows-xp-updated-clock-daylight-savings-time/AnswerViewer.do?requestId=8605229), regardless of connection to the internet. More [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/914387) on daylight saving time updates have been issued for Windows since 2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need to make a batch file with only 1 line (Presumably named DaylightSaving-1h.bat or something):

```
time 01:00
```

And also a second one with

```
time 22:00
```

Then you need to have 2 scheduled tasks running once a year. The first one to chane the time back one hour, running at 23:00 the first Saturday in October. The second one to change the time forward one hour, running at 00:00 the first Sunday in April.

Comment: Mofi, I cant use the auto adjust so its turned off. I cant have it update untill after 3am and auto adjusts at 2am....

Comment: @SoggyCashew please mark this answer as the correct one if it gave you the right solution or helped you to find it.